# Telegram bot ( telegraf.js library ) forwarding messages from one to another channel method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm making a news bot, and need to forward fresh last posted messages from my main channel to another ones.

How can I do it?

```
// This method to send message to channel, and after I send message I need to forward it to another channels
bot.telegram.sendMessage("@channel", `SOME TEXT`, { parse_mode: 'Markdown' });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found **forwardMessage** method, here it is:
https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=forwardmessage